# Как оптимальнее считать значения в двумерный массив?

Tags: массивы, php

Вопрос обобщённый.
Имеем текстовые файлы, из которых нужно считать массив.
Структура файлов примерно следующая:

```
Произвольный текст...
Array = new Array([integer, float, hex, xxx, xxx, number, ...., xxx, str, 50, 300],
                  [integer, float, float, hex, xxx, xxx, ...., xxx, str, 50, 200],
                   ...,
                  [float, float, hex, xxx, xxx, number, ...., xxx, str, 50, 100],
                  [integer, float, float, xxx, xxx, num, ...., xxx, str, 50, 31]]);
Произвольный текст...
```

Получается, что нахожу регуляркой строку между `([` и`])`, разбиваю по разделителям, потом каждую `[]` с помощью `explode()` по разделителям считываю всё в массив.

Или пишу большую длинную регулярку для одной строки массива (менее универсально, и приходится под разные массивы подстраиваться отдельно; работает вроде медленнее, но код компактнее) и с помощью `preg_match_all` всё делю и пишу в массив.

В результате всех операций выстраивается изначально заданный массив в том же самом виде, что довольно странно. :)

Потому и возник данный вопрос: можно ли это осуществить проще?

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, что данный скрипт не будет использоваться в промышленных масштабах. Даже если парсинг текста и создание массива займет минуту - никому хуже не станет. Обратите только внимание, что через месяц вам не захочется копаться в регулярке для внесения изменений и запуска скрипта с измененным текстом для парсинга. Лучше пишите проще - через explode.

**Обновление**

Вы для каждого посетителя, что ли, хотите запускать парсинг вашего файла?

Обычно делается так: файл парсится один раз, массив записывается в кеш (или в отдельный файл или в памяти хранится), для всех посетителей файл берется из кеша. При загрузке файла с новыми данными он парсится в момент загрузки и кеш обновляется. Во время парсинга посетители мгновенно получают старые данные, после того как кеш обновился - новые. Главное слово - мгновенно, т.к. не требуется постоянно разбирать текст, а можно сразу работать с данными.

Формат JSON или массив со скобками - для хранения все равно.

Comment: В промышленных не будет, информация используется для представления на страницах сайта... Потому минута много. Он отрабатывает секунд за 5, и это неприятная задержка при открытии каждой страницы.

Данные часто меняются, новые получаются именно в таком виде, потому нет какого-то препроцесса для создания из них БД и обращения к ней.

А что если заменить пару скобок и подогнать строку под формат JSON, а потом работать с ним стандартными средствами... Будет быстрее в теории?

Comment: @Isaev, обновил ответ.

Comment: Как в памяти не представляю... Это же скрипт, он отработал и память потёрлась. Или примерчик бы не помешал.

А в файле к тому же и вернулись, разве что без первой регулярки, которая сам массив достаёт. Чтобы его снова считать, нужно снова парсить точно так же ведь?

Comment: Можно считать все содержимое файла как переменную и работать с ней, как с массивом. Исключая сложный парсинг, на кторый тратится 90% времени. Можно в файле написать создание массива и инклудить его в скрипт. Про хранение в памяти прочитайте про memcache.